# MVC Custom Routes and ActionLinks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

We are working with an asp.net mvc app that is shared by multiple clients.  We need the urls to include the clients url friendly name.  For example:

domain.com/clientName/controller/action/id

This below appears to be working when it comes to routing, but the "clientName" is not generated correctly for the action link helpers.

```
_routes.MapRoute("DefaultRoute",
                "{clientName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = string.Empty },
                new { clientName = @"[\w-]+" });
```

We would like to continue using the Html.ActionLink Helper methods, but it does not include the clientName in the generated link.  Do we have to write our own helpers in this scenario or is there an alternative approach?

Has anyone else built an application with this type of routing scenario?  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do should work without having to use RouteLink or specifying an anonymous object.  Make sure your route registrations are correct.  For example, if you have something like:

```
routes.MapRoute("Base", 
                string.Empty,
                new { controller = "Home", 
                action = "Index", 
                id = string.Empty });
```

before your **DefaultRoute**, it can cause calls to ActionLink to return strange results. I've been burned by this before.

Answer (score 11):

It's been my experience that the ActionLink method referenced by Darin will generate a URL like:

```
http://host/Home/action?clientName=someClient
```

If you want to generate the URL exactly as you specified. Check out the [RouteLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink.aspx) method that lets you specify the name of the Route you are matching:

```
<%= Html.RouteLink("some text", "DefaultRoute", new { clientName = "someclient" })%>
```

Comment: @Bryan, I've tested the code I provided and it generated the expected url. Maybe in your case you put the routes declaration in the wrong order and it was the catch-all route that was executed. Specific routes should be put before the catch-all route.

Comment: Great answer, I was having the very same issue while experimenting with MVCContrib Portable Area routing. Not it works like a charm.

Comment: RouteLink also worked for me where ActionLink did not for a route I have checked and double-checked. Frustrating that I don't know if I'm failing to understanding route configs, or ActionLink is doing something weird.

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify route values:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("some text", "action", new { clientName = "someclient" })%>
```

Will generate:

```
http://host/someclient/Home/action
```

You could also specify a default value when declaring the route:

```
_routes.MapRoute("DefaultRoute",
    "{clientName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { 
        controller = "Home", 
        action = "Index", 
        id = string.Empty, 
        clientName = "defaultClient" },
    new { clientName = @"[\w-]+" });
```

Comment: This works a charm. As you said in another comment you have to put the catch all route last or you may get unexpected results